# Understanding PostgreSQL Execution Plans

Tags: postgresql, join, execution-plan, postgresql-12

I'm trying to understand the motivation of PostgreSQL 12 query planner here.

**Database Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE subjects
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE metadata
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    label TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE subject_metadata
(
    subject_id INT REFERENCES subjects (id),
    metadata_id INT REFERENCES metadata (id),

    nval BIGINT NULL,
    strval TEXT null,
    values JSONB NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(subject_id, metadata_id)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_subject_metadata_values ON
   subject_metadata(subject_id, metadata_id, strval, nval);
```

**Data Set**

Table `subjects` contains ~10 million rows, table `metadata` ~1000 rows and `subject_metadata` ~400 million rows.

**Query**

I need to run queries for `subject` having 1 to N `metadata` references. So my naive approach was to simply join `subject_metadata` for each queried metadata:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, dmd1.strval, dmd2.nval as lang 
FROM subjects d
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd1 on dmd1.subject_id = d.id
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd2 on dmd2.subject_id = d.id
WHERE d.name > '0' 
  AND (dmd1.metadata_id = 2 AND dmd1.strval = 'us') 
  AND (dmd2.metadata_id = 16 AND dmd2.nval > 100)
ORDER BY d.name
LIMIT 100
```

This works quite well for two joins with query times < 80ms. Plan:  https://explain.depesz.com/s/PgXg

Joining `subject_metadata` a third time leads to a drastic performance drop. The following query - which only differs from the original by an additional join - takes 43 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, dmd1.strval, dmd2.nval as lang 
FROM subjects d
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd1 on dmd1.subject_id = d.id
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd2 on dmd2.subject_id = d.id
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd3 on dmd3.subject_id = d.id
WHERE d.name > '0' 
  AND (dmd1.metadata_id = 2 AND dmd1.strval = 'us') 
  AND (dmd2.metadata_id = 16 AND dmd2.nval > 100)
  AND dmd3.metadata_id = 605
ORDER BY d.name
LIMIT 100
```

Plan:  https://explain.depesz.com/s/sNrU

Rewriting this query by changing the order of join (joining `subjects` last), brings the performance in line with the first query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, dmd1.strval, dmd2.nval as lang 
FROM subject_metadata dmd1
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd2 on dmd2.subject_id = dmd1.subject_id
  JOIN subject_metadata dmd3 on dmd3.subject_id = dmd2.subject_id
  JOIN subjects d on dmd3.subject_id = d.id
WHERE d.name > '0' 
  AND (dmd1.metadata_id = 2 AND dmd1.strval = 'us') 
  AND (dmd2.metadata_id = 16 AND dmd2.nval > 100)
  AND dmd3.metadata_id = 605
ORDER BY d.name
LIMIT 100
```

This version completes in 150ms. Plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/XEjL

I would like to understand why re-ordering the joins makes such a huge difference and/or if there's even a better way to implement this.